# Checking a given non-symmetric matrix is positive definite.

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Hi I was wondering whether the following matrix is positive definite or not?

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 9 & 3 &3\\3 & 10 & 7\\3 & 5 & 9\end{bmatrix}$$

Clearly A is not symmetric, but since

$$det\begin{bmatrix} 9\end{bmatrix}>0,\,det\begin{bmatrix} 9 & 3\\
3 & 10\end{bmatrix}>0,\,\,\,det\begin{bmatrix} 9 & 3 &3\\3 & 10 & 7\\3 & 5 & 9\end{bmatrix}>0$$

A is positive definite, right?? (Symmetry is not necessary to be Positive Definite)

Am I right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your definition of positive-definiteness?

Comment: duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156974/how-to-check-if-a-matrix-is-positive-definite?

Answer (score 1):

apply the test to
$$H=\begin{bmatrix} 9 & 3 &3\\3 & 10 & 6\\3 & 6 & 9\end{bmatrix}$$
which is the symmetric part of your matrix, that is $H = (A + A^T)/2.$ The quadratic forms (for column vector $x$)
$$  x^T Hx = x^T A x $$
because adding or subtracting a skew-symmetric matrix does not change the quadratic form; only the symmetric part matters.

$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
9 & 3 & 3 \\ 
3 & 10 & 6 \\ 
3 & 6 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
9 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & 9 & 5 \\ 
3 & 5 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
9 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 9 & 5 \\ 
0 & 5 & 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 9 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 27 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 9 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 9 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
9 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 9 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 47 }{ 9 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 4 }{ 27 }  &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 9 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
9 & 3 & 3 \\ 
3 & 10 & 6 \\ 
3 & 6 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 27 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 9 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
9 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 9 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 47 }{ 9 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 9 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
9 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 9 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 47 }{ 9 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 9 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
9 & 3 & 3 \\ 
3 & 10 & 6 \\ 
3 & 6 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$