# symmeric bilinear form defined by the following matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

what is the signature of the symmeric bilinear form defined by the following matrix

$\left(\begin{matrix} 
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -5\\
  0 & 0& 0 & -5 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & -5 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & -5 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{matrix}\right)$

i was thinking that  sigantutre =$2p-r $ where p is a numberof positive entries and r is the ranks of the given matrix

so her p=1  and r= 5  and signature $=2.1-5=-3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Sylvester, since $\det(1)=1$ and $\det(M_{5\times5})>0$  the signature can be

**1.** $+++++$

**2.** $+++--$

**3.** $+----$

Case 1 can be excluded since

$$\det(M_{2\times2})=\begin{vmatrix}0&-5\\-5&0\end{vmatrix}=-25 <0$$

thus we have at least one negative eigenvalue. Moreover

$$\det(M_{3\times3})=\begin{vmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&-5\\0&-5&0\end{vmatrix}=-25 <0$$

has signature $++-$ then also case 3 can be excluded.

Then the signature is $$n_+=3 \quad n_-=2 \quad n_0=0$$

Comment: i found  ur answer  easier...as  but im  not  getting  that u have   said that  but since there is $\det(M_{2x2})$ <0...i  mean  which$ 2\times2 $matrix u r talking about ?

Comment: @  gimusi   why u didn't take $det({M_{3\times 3}} )$??

Comment: @lomber I've edited with some detail more and also with a discussion to exclude also the case $+----$ not considered in the earlier version. Please do not hesitate for any further clarification.

Comment: thanks    a  lots @gimusi,,why  ur account was suspended ??yesterday

Comment: @lomber You are welcome, I’m happy that you can appreciate my suggestion. For the suspension you can find some detail here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28331/how-to-deal-with-defamations-perpetrated-through-public-chat-rooms

Answer (score 2):

This is **congruence** diagonalization of your matrix, I am calling it $H.$ The entires of $D$ are not the eigenvalues, but they have the exact same counts of positive, negative, zero. As you can see, three positive, two negative. Oh, as I arranged to have $\det P = \pm 1,$ the determinant is the same as the determinant of $D.$

Using the letters in the question, $p = 3, r = 5,$ $2p-r = 6-5 = 1$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 5 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 10 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Begins with $D_0 = H,$ after which we find useful elementary matrices $E_j \; :$

$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 5 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 10 & 0 & 0 &  - 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 5 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 5 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 5 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 10 &  - 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 5 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 10 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 5 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 10 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 10 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 5 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: thanks  a lots @Will Jagy,,

Comment: @WillJagy why perform all this long calculation to determine signature? in't it convenoent to use Sulvester? Thanks

Comment: @gimusi this method is also due to Sylvester. I added a similar answer to a question from when the site first began, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58010/determining-if-a-quadratic-polynomial-is-always-positive/2625830#2625830  As far as taste, I like the concrete aspect of this, you get a diagonal matrix and just look at the diagonal entries. Finding the diagonal matrix is algorithmic (well, this way of finding it is), see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr