# Is there is any result on computing the eigenvalues or signs of the eigenvalues of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is there is any result on computing the eigenvalues or signs of the eigenvalues of a matrix?

I dont know any result, but I'm pretty sure that there must be some result on evaluating the signs of the eigenvalues of a matrix without computing its so called characteristic equation or simply what would be the eigenvalues.

Comment: no such thing. Meanwhile, you are going to learn the material better if you do the exercises the way they are asked. This applies either way, whether you are getting homework in an organized class, or just studying on your own

Comment: No sir I'm studying my own & also I dont have any intention to learn short tricks rather than I just want result/Theorem not any visualization, I think in that there is no wrong

Comment: Also dont knowing any result is'nt wrong right? so sir I just want to know those result & you know sir every book does not contain every result not even exercises.

Comment: If there is any result let me know sir

Comment: Alright. For a general square matrix, there is no good way to tell how many real and how many complex eigenvalues there might be. For special cases, such as symmetric real matrices, there are other approaches, but still nothing amazingly quick

Comment: sorry sir. my actual querry is the sign of the eigen value whether it is real, for eg if A is symmetric matrix then by computing in any way cant we say how many +ve real or how many -ve real eigen value

Answer (score 1):

One of the implications of Law of Inertia of matrices is "For any symmetric matrix $A$, the signs of the pivots agree with the signs of the eigenvalues."

So by doing elimination on matrix $A$ and finding out its pivots, we can comment on the number of positivea and negative eigenvalues of $A$

Comment: Check out this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57887/how-does-number-of-signs-of-pivots-same-as-number-of-signs-of-eigenvalues-help-i?rq=1) on how the signs of pivots agree with signs of eigenvalues

Comment: But which operation we have to do on the symmetric matrix A?

Comment: row reduced echelon form?

Comment: Yes, with row reduced echelon form, you get all pivots on the diagonal

Comment: their sign wil be the sign of the eigen value but they are not eigen value right?

Comment: yes. pivots and eigenvalues of a matrix correspond to different entities. I would suggest you to read through both concepts before attempting to solve questions directly